# Unsupported RPL stream version detected: 101.116.1047292257. Expected version: 10.6

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, error-reporting

When I run the SSRS report in Visual Studio I'm able to run the report but when I execute the report through the report server it's throwing the below error any help.

```
Error :
An error occurred during client rendering.
Unsupported RPL stream version detected: 101.116.1047292257. Expected version: 10.6.
```

Comment: Hey Kapil, Did you find the root cause of this issue or a way to fix this? This just started happening with one of my servers.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the reportserver database was set to full logging and filled up the log disk

Answer (score 0):

When I had this it was due to a filter on a parameter missing a 0 between the brackets

I had
NOT(Parameters!Milestones.Value

but it had to be
NOT(Parameters!Milestones.Value(0)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the ReportServer database was corrupt, running this script solved the problem

`USE master;`
`ALTER DATABASE [ReportServer] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;`
`GO`
`DBCC CHECKDB ('ReportServer', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;`
`GO`
`ALTER DATABASE ReportServer SET MULTI_USER;`
`GO`

`USE master;`
`ALTER DATABASE [ReportServerTempDB] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;`
`GO`
`DBCC CHECKDB ('ReportServerTempDB', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;`
`GO`
`ALTER DATABASE ReportServerTempDB SET MULTI_USER;`
`GO`

Answer (score 0):

I had a report where the HIDDEN formula was returning a 1 or 0 instead of "true" or "false"

the designer gave the message about the stream version.

the report portal actually gave a message that the HIDDEN equation for the tablix was the wrong type.  1000% better error message.